# Connecting a loop in sculpting mode

Tags: sculpting

I have a sculpted piece. I would like to connect the loop in sculpting mode.

How to do it?

Of course, I know I should have made it before going into sculpting.

If I go into edit mode, the mesh is too dense to find correct edge to bridge them. I would like to do it in sculpting mode.

[image]

Comment: Would a "self-union" work? http://www.darenscotwilson.com/spec/selfunion/selfunion.html

Comment: I have to try this because my object is 2D surface.